# I need help on ---> If statement: after the page loads, then do this

Tags: c#, load, click, execute

Please I need help on the code below "if (webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted);"

This is the event I want to happen after I click the button:
1.) Retrieve Webpage
2.) If Webpage is done loading, then fill the form attribute

I am stuck at number 2. How do you make an "IF" statement that has to do with the page after loading

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
webBrowser1.Navigate("costco.com/Common/Login.aspx?cm_re=1_en-_-Top_Right_Nav-_-Top_login&topnav=&whse=BC&lang=en-US")


  if (webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted);
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_ctl0_EmailAddress").SetAttribute("value", "RogerWilliams");
```

}

There's an error with "if (webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted);"

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow. When you say "There's an error", the very next thing you should do is explain what the error is, including the *exact* error message you're getting. Please edit your question to provide it, and remember when you do that we can't see your screen from here - we only have what you tell us in your question to use to try and help you. If you ask a better question, you have a better chance of getting an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentCompleted` is not a boolean property, it is an event which will occur asynchronously. You should create a callback which will be called once the event is fired.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(OnDocumentCompleted);
    webBrowser1.Navigate("costco.com/Common/Login.aspx?cm_re=1_en-_-Top_Right_Nav-_-Top_login&topnav=&whse=BC&lang=en-US");
}

private void OnDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementById("_ctl0_EmailAddress").SetAttribute("value", "RogerWilliams");
}
```

Comment: @Barry please use my solution instead. Your solution indeed works, but it takes up CPU in this `while` cycle. My solution works as well, but it is event-based, which is the standard and preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with ajax in jquery like so:

```
 $('#yourlink').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'costco.com/Common/Login.aspx?cm_re=1_en-_-Top_Right_Nav-_-Top_login&topnav=&whse=BC&lang=en-US',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#_ctl0_EmailAddress').val('RogerWilliams');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Shedal's answer is correct. DocumentCompleted is an event handler and is invoked when the browser finished loading the document. However, if you explicitly need to get the current status of the document, you can use the WebBrowser.ReadyState and check to see if the document is loaded or not. Here is the link to different ReadyState properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserreadystate.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the extra semicolon at the end of the `if` statement:

```
if (webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted)
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_ctl0_EmailAddress").SetAttribute("value", "RogerWilliams");
```

Comment: The semicolon is just a typo. The real problem is described in my asnswer.

Comment: Maybe it is a typo, but it is definitely one of the errors in the code.